# Getting parameters of Spark submit while running a Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I am running a spark job by spark-submit and using its --files parameter to load a log4j.properties file.

In my Spark job I need to get this parameter

```
object LoggerSparkUsage {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
//DriverHolder.log.info("unspark")
println("args are....."+args.mkString(" "))
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple_Application")//.setMaster("local[4]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 // conf.getExecutorEnv.
val count = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3)).count()
println("these are files"+conf.get("files"))
LoggerDriver.log.info("log1 for info..")
LoggerDriver.log.info("log2 for infor..")
f2

}
def f2{LoggerDriver.log.info("logs from another function..")}

}
```

my spark submit is something like this:
    /opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-submit  --class "LoggerSparkUsage" --master yarn-client --files src/main/resources/log4j.properties /mapr/cellos-mapr/user/mbazarganigilani/SprkHbase/target/scala-2.10/sprkhbase_2.10-1.0.2.jar

I tried to get the properties using
conf.get("files")

but it gives me an exception

can anyone give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

A correct key for files is `spark.files`:

```
scala.util.Try(sc.getConf.get("spark.files"))
```

but to get actual path on the workers you have to use `SparkFiles`:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get(fileName)
```

If it is not sufficient you can pass these second as application arguments and retrieve from `main` args or use custom key in `spark.conf`.

Comment: Hi , I need to get the exact parameter I sent to spark submit ("src/main/resources/log4j.properties")..actually when I used scala.util.Try(sc.getConf.get("spark.files")) it gave me a null values exception . using the second commnd gave me an adress in a temp directory on the cluster...